# min a linear function and max a convex function over a bounded polytope

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Consider a bounded polytop $P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \geq b\}$, we know the extreme points of $P$ are $p_1, p_2, ..., p_r$.

Then consider the following two problem:
$$\min e^T(x + \mid x\mid)$$
$$s.t. x \in P$$

where $\mid x\mid = \begin{bmatrix}\mid x_1\mid \\ \mid x_2\mid \\ \vdots \\ \mid x_n\mid\end{bmatrix}$.

$$\max e^T(\mid x\mid - x  )$$
$$s.t. x \in P$$

For the min problem, we can transform it into a linear program by introducing $\mid x\mid \leq t$.  As for the max problem, I think it can not be transformed into a LP since the objective function is convex.

My question is how to solve these two problems based on known information. Can we check every extreme points to get the optimal solution?

---

I think we can solve the max problem by checking every extreme points.

Let $v(x) =  e^T(\mid x\mid - x  )$, then it is a convex function.

By Jensen’s inequality, we know for any point $ \bar{x} \in P$, $v(\bar{x}) = v(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r} \lambda_i p_i) \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_iv(p_i) \leq \max_{i \in \{1, 2, ..., r\}}v(p_i)$.

Comment: you are correct, this is known as the [maximum principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752555/theorem-for-the-optimization-of-linear-function-over-a-bounded-polyhedron/3752665#3752665)

Comment: How about the min problem.

Comment: you should transform it to a linear optimization problem as you say, the solution can be in the interior of $P$

Comment: Could you explain more about why the solution can be in the interior of $P$?

Comment: upon closer inspection it cannot be in the interior for this specific function, but it can be on a facet, I'll post an example below

Comment: Thank you!@LinAlg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the minimum, it does not suffice to compare the function values at the extreme points. For example, take the polyhedron $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x-(0.9,0.9)||_1 \leq 1\}$. The function values at the extreme points are $f((-0.1,0.9)) = f((0.9,-0.1) = 1.8$, $f((1.9,0.9)) = f((0.9,1.9))=5.6$, but $f((0.4, 0.4))=1.6$.

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem and find the optimal solution is (-0.0132, -0.9034) which is not an extreme point.

Comment: @oneuser that point does not seem feasible though (the 1-norm is approximately 2.7)

Comment: Sorry, I mistaken the parameters. Optimal solution is (0.4,0.4).